# Matplotlib: Increase ax.matshow width/height, and set color map (cmap) to transparent

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, axes, colormap

I have a matrix built of random values and I plotted it with `ax.matplot`, where the  value of each matrix cell is plotted in the center of the matrix cell, and I need to increase the size of the plot (specially the width) and also set the color map (cmap) to "transparent", where the cells of the matrix plot will be **white** and the matrix value in the center of the cell with be **black**.

**The code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

low_dim = 0
high_dim = 20

matrix = np.random.randint(low_dim, high_dim, (high_dim,high_dim))
print (matrix)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.matshow(matriz, cmap=None,interpolation='nearest')

for i in xrange(20):
    for j in xrange(20):
        number = matrix[j,i]
        ax.text(i, j, str(number), va='center', ha='center')


plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

That's `matrix` in the code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3mGO.png  (**matrix**), a matrix generated with the command  `matrix = np.random.randint(low_dim, high_dim, (high_dim,high_dim))`, the picture is from the console.

I've tried changing the **figsize** in `fig,ax = plt.subplot()`,but it doesn't change anything. And I've also set `cmap = none` but nothing happened.

**Another problem** is that, in the first picture, the numbers in the index of x and y axes are varying from 0 to 15 and stepping 5, like 0, 5, 10, 15 (I've marked it in red). But in the second picture (also marked in red), the values are from 0 to 19,with no step. If possible, I need to arrive to the second picture's result, the indexes varying from 0 to 19 with no step.

**Picture 1:  What I'm getting:**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlExQ.png

**Picture 2:  What I need to get:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3CC4.png

Comment: What is `matrix` in your code? And if you use Python 2.7, you should tag the question accordingly.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: I would have hoped, [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matshow takes arguments for origin and alpha. The rest is just settings ticks and labels.

```
ax.matshow(matrix, origin='lower', alpha=0, cmap=None, interpolation='nearest')

tick_labels = range(high_dim)
ax.set_xticks([], minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 20, 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks([], minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 20, 1), minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels([], minor=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels, minor=True)
ax.set_yticklabels([], minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(tick_labels, minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.grid(which='minor', color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
```

Comment: I ran the code and the result was a little problem I faced before and wasn't capable of solving:  That's the resulted matrix in the console (I print it first in the console to check if the plot code is fine) ---> https://i.imgur.com/JpS5ZJF.jpg, and that's the plot  generated --->  https://i.imgur.com/4RRiXU3.jpg.  Notice that the lines are "upside down", and so are the index of y axis (19 at top, 0 at bottom). How could I soulve that?

Comment: If you want to have your origin in the upper left corner, you can set `origin='upper'`